# javascript based local file explorer

Tags: javascript, html

Does anybody know a javascript based local file explorer?
It should explore visitor's file system.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You mean from a remote website? Impossible in JavaScript.

You'd need a Java applet to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to do this in a browser, it won't be possible due to sandbox security.